# Exec local executable with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, exec

**Can't find over the network the solution, so desided to ask here**

I have a [such structure of a project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB3FZ.png)

What I want: I want ProcessBuilder to use my local adb.exe

For example my String[] for ProcessBuilder:

```
case "devicesListString":
    String[] devicesListString = {"./adb.exe","devices"};
    return devicesListString;
```

This is how ProcessBuilder initiates

```
public Process initNewProcessBuilderOnProcess(Tab tab, String[] str) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder vr = new ProcessBuilder(str);
    vr.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
    vr.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process pr = vr.start();
    tabAndProcessMap.put(tab, pr);
    return pr;
}
```

vr.directory added, but no result.
How can I access my resource of adb.exe?
Maybe I need something else, not ProcessBuilder?

Comment: Is adb.exe in same directory as your Java app?

Comment: @SteveSmith https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB3FZ.png look here pls.
I want to include it, may be libs or so on.

Comment: You need to specify the correct path!

Comment: @SteveSmith I need it to suit dynamicaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not reliable to assume an application resource is an actual file.  Instead, use one of Java’s getResource* methods to read the resource, and copy it to an actual file:

```
Path adb = Files.createTempFile("adb", ".exe");

try (InputStream stream = Testinghelper.class.getResourceAsStream("adb.exe")) {
    Files.copy(stream, adb, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(adb.toString(), "devices");
```

On operating systems other than Windows, it probably would be necessary to make the new file executable, before passing it to ProcessBuilder:

```
PosixFileAttributeView view =
    Files.getFileAttributeView(adb, PosixFileAttributeView.class);
if (view != null) {
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = view.readAttributes().permissions();
    if (perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE)) {
        view.setPermissions(adb, perms);
    }
}
```